# direct LAN keeps PC Fans on after power off

Tags: fan, lan, disconnect

So I set up my banan PI with a ubuntu running on it with a direct lan connection to my PC with windows. When I shut down my PC fans will keep running and there is a buzzing sound coming from it. This keeps going even if I disconnect my PC from the power (unpluged it).

Any one got an idea how to fix that?